# Can anyone identify these parts?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

They're round and like a platform.  On the bottom are three steel balls.  When you place down or tap, the red LED lights blink.  One has a skull and fire on its sides.

[image: Text]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Are there any markings on this that say LEGO? On the studs for example?

Comment: Can you please send another image of the other side without the lights on? Do these parts look like they are compatible with lego (its ok if they from clone brand)?

Comment: My guess was that this was one of their [games](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Games), but I don't see it if it is.  More pictures would be very helpful.

Comment: You're right, it may be a clone. No LEGO markings. It says MEGA I can make out on the bottom.
![1](https://newvisionpress.files.wordpress.com/2020/08/img_4637.png?w=246&h=185)
![2](https://newvisionpress.files.wordpress.com/2020/08/img_4638.png?w=246&h=185)
![3](https://newvisionpress.files.wordpress.com/2020/08/img_4640.png?w=246&h=185)
![4](https://newvisionpress.files.wordpress.com/2020/08/img_4643.png?w=246&h=185)
![5](https://newvisionpress.files.wordpress.com/2020/08/img_4644.png?w=246&h=185)

Comment: MEGA Bloks. Now to find out what game or set.

Comment: My guess: Looks like two Mega Bloks Skylanders Battle Portals. Who can confirm?

Answer (score 6):

With thanks to Uli,

Mega Bloks Skylanders Battle Portals

[image]

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you all for your help!